# Is there the only one way to insert custom layouts in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I created a custom `RelativeLayout` named `RemoteImageView`.

```xml
<com.mypackagepath.RemoteImageView
              xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <!-- something interesting -->
</com.mypackagepath.RemoteImageView>
```

Should I always write

```xml
<include layout="@layout/remote_image_view" />
```

when I want to place it somewhere or I can somehow write

```xml
<com.mypackagepath.RemoteImageView etc="something" />
```

?

Comment: you can use <com.mypackagepath.RemoteImageView /> like your example. both of them are right

Comment: This method doesn't work, that's why I am asking. It's correct but it doesn't appear.

Comment: it worked with me all the time make sure you copy your package name maybe you miss character or something

Comment: No, there are no syntax errors. It simply doesn't appear

Comment: I noticed something when you said you made custom layout you mean like extend RelativeLayout or you make new xml file named remote_image_view

Comment: I have the XML `remote_image_view.xml` with `com.mypackagepath.RemoteImageView` (which is in the topic post) and the custom class `RemoteImage` which extends `RelativeLayout` and related to this XML.